# Binary to String using Google.Protobuf

Tags: c#, visual-studio, type-conversion, protocol-buffers, binaryfiles

I'm trying to take a .txt file which icontains some binary. E.g.

```
&
ns16A086C66661C9   D%  C(0 ¢À
&
ns167C0BC683548A €\D% €‹C(0 ¢À
&
ns16BC3BAF56248CÍ=D%¤pìC(0 ¢À
&
ns16A89FBA902317q%¤D%"÷C(0 ¢À
&
ns16EC1F720BB5983ó1C%×C(0ž¢À
&
ns1690E7C450794F ÀD% €ŠC(0 ¢À
&
ns16A408EAB24E2Fš©ED%…‹éC(0 ¢À
&
ns16F832E429A2C4 @{D% €ÍC(0 ¢À
&
ns160CD74622F0D3
—yD%ÍløC(0 ¢À
&
ns16485A3F0BA1D7öˆyD%…+¹C(0ž¢À
&
ns16EC35866601D4 @HD% ÀD(0 ¢À
&
ns1660F189ED2318  «D%  èB(0 ¢À
&
ns16
```

to change it into string. However I do not know how to approach this using **Google.Protobuf's** library.

This is what I have now, I can't seem to figure out how to parse the data read from the .txt, put it through Google.Protobuf's decoder??? and get the string out proper.

```
namespace ConsoleApplicationTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            byte[] array = File.ReadAllBytes("C:/brokerdata.txt");

            Google.Protobuf.IMessage<string> a = new IMessage<string>();
            Google.Protobuf.MessageParser<a> bb = new MessageParser<a>(() => "");
            bb.ParseFrom(array);

            string s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(array, 0, array.Length);
            Console.Out.WriteLine(s);
            Console.WriteLine("First byte: {0}", array[0]);
            Console.WriteLine("Last byte: {0}", array[array.Length - 1]);
            Console.WriteLine(array.Length);
            //Console.Out.WriteLine(array);
            Console.ReadKey();
                }
         }
}
```

Comment: "Text file which is in binary" doesn't make sense - is it a text file, or is it binary? It sounds like it's really just binary data. What are `a` and `b` here? (You shouldn't need to create your own `MessageParser` instance.) It's unclear how the data in the file relates to protocol buffers...

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, I apologise (will edit it), it is binary. A&B are just place holders. I did not know that I shouldn't need to create my own MessageParser for that. How do I go about this? Could you perhaps guide me? Thank you!

Comment: Well do you have a .proto file? Where are your messages declared? It's still really unclear what's actually meant to be in this file, or what it has to do with protocol buffers...

Comment: @JonSkeet I will ask my colleagues and get back to you! Thank you for your response! :)